# Find command with exec echo option contains ./ in filename

Tags: linux, shell, find

How can I avoid displaying leading ./  from the output ?

**Real Output**

> ```
> test@testmachine:/usr/lib$ find . -name "*" -exec echo {} \;
> .
> ./pymodules/python2.7/pyliblzma-0.5.3.egg-info
> ./pymodules/python2.7/pyliblzma-0.5.3.egg-info/PKG-INFO
> ./pymodules/python2.7/pyliblzma-0.5.3.egg-info/top_level.txt
> ./pymodules/python2.7/pyliblzma-0.5.3.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
> ./pymodules/python2.7/pyliblzma-0.5.3.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
> ```

**Required output:**

> ```
> test@testmachine:/usr/lib$ find . -name "*" -exec xxxxxxxxxx \;
>
> pymodules/python2.7/pyliblzma-0.5.3.egg-info
> pymodules/python2.7/pyliblzma-0.5.3.egg-info/PKG-INFO
> pymodules/python2.7/pyliblzma-0.5.3.egg-info/top_level.txt
> pymodules/python2.7/pyliblzma-0.5.3.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
> pymodules/python2.7/pyliblzma-0.5.3.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't specify `.` as the search directory.

```
find * -exec echo {} \;
```

The `-name '*'` part of your command does not eliminate names starting with a `.` but the globbing does.  If it's a problem, then add `.[!.]*` before the `-exec` (that skips `.` and `..`, but also `..hidden`; you decide whether that matters).